# Appy Html Agility Pack Changes to Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack

I've used the Html Agility Pack to read/parse HTML elements' values for Coded UI Tests (automated UI testing).

Example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='a'> 
      <input name="inp" value="some input"> </input>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Grab div with id='a'.

```
       HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode divNode = 
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='a']//input[@name='inp']");
Console.WriteLine(divNode.Attributes["value"].Value); // prints out "some input"
```

I could modify the div's "value" in memory by doing `divNode.SetAttribute("value", "new value");`.

However, what if I want to actually apply/write this updated value to the web page?

Can I do this with the Html Agility Pack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for modifying a document is something like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("somefile.html");

// modify doc in memory

doc.Save("somefile.html");
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I can see how `doc.Save(...)` would work if I'm hitting  a local HTML file (C:/workspace/testing/hapTest.html). However, if I wanted to use `doc.Save(...)` when hitting a locally hosted (via IIS) HTML page, I'd have to specify exactly where on disk the file lives to save?

Comment: Yes, sure, Save takes a file full path input, or you can give it a Stream object (for example if you want to send the file on the wire directly without an intermediary physical file)

Comment: And to implement this, I would save the `HtmlDocument` to a concrete implementation of `System.IO.Stream`, and then call `htmlDoc.save(stream)`? Will I actually have write permissions on the local host? I'm looking to this way of modifying HTML rather than using `Mouse.Click` and `Keyboard.SendKeys`.

Comment: Permissions depends on the stream but that's the idea.